# Using Objectify to filter datastore entity by date is not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

The following method keeps returning nothing and I don't understand why. The `modified` field is indexed in the entity as

```
@Index
private Date modified;
```

Here is the method that is not working:

```
public static List<Dog> getAllModifiedDogs(Date modified) {
    return OfyService.ofy().load().type(Dog.class).filter("modified > ", modified).list();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've recently added the entities concerned, and they haven't had time to propagate? When you create them, you should get an ID which can be used for a key lookup, which will always be strongly consistent.

Comment: so I waited for a whole day to test your idea and that's not the case. I still get nothing even now. Have you used my approach before and have it work?

Comment: and if I have pre-existing entities with the same index and then do a deploy to app engine on android studio, that shouldn't change anything as the index is not new.

Comment: Are you possibly creating the entities in the local development server's datastore, and the datastore in production is empty for the Dog kind? Check the [Developers' Console](http://console.cloud.google.com) Datastore section to see.

Comment: They are finally showing up. It looks like I might have added some stuff before `@Index`ing the field. So after I added new ones, those show up. That part of Objectify/Datastore always gets me.

Comment: Ah great to hear. You should add this as a self-answer!

Comment: yeah! adding @Index starts to work!